# Why do some line of code doesn't execute after a loop?

Tags: javascript, api, flickr

I am newbie with javascript and trying to play with API, I don't know why there are some lines of code don't execute after the for loop is done. Could anyone help me ?

```
function jsonFlickrApi(data) {
    if (data.stat != 'ok') {
        alert('no image loaded');
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i <= data.photos.photo.length; i++) {
            addImage(data.photos.photo[i].url_o);
            var lat = data.photos.photo[i].latitude;
            var lon = data.photos.photo[i].longitude;
            var LatLon = {
                lat: parseFloat(lat),
                lng: parseFloat(lon)
            };

            var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                'position': LatLon,
                'map': map,
            });

            console.log("i", i);
            photoMarkers.push(markers);
            //It still executes well here.
        };
        //After the loop is finished, it doesn't print out anything to the console.
        console.log("here");
    };
    //The following line doesn't execute too
    fitMap(photoMarkers);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That loop doesn't finish, it throws an exception. Open your web console to see the details, you'll find something like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url_o' of undefined
```

Array indexes are `0` through `length-1`, so you want your `for` loop to be `< data.photos.photo.length`, not `<= data.photos.photo.length`. On the last iteration of your `<=` loop, `data.photos.photo[i]` is `undefined` so trying to get the value of `data.photos.photo[i].url_o` throws.

Comment: Thank you so much, it helps me a lot :)